# CSS menu using on hover which prevents input from getting focus

Tags: css

I adapted this menu from a tutorial. There were some things that did not work so I had to make changes. I am however a complete css php novice.
The problem that I am having is that the on hover which is the key to this menu causes the input boxes to be covered by an invisible layer which prevents them from getting the focus.
If you click on the bottom of the page and move up it will work but if you first go over the menu it does not. I have tried many things to fix this but with my limited CSS ability I have not been
able to  fix this.
All help will be appreciated
Thanks

It needs an image but it appears that as a new member I cannot post the image :(
here is a link to where I got it from and the image is there
http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/91/index.html

CSS

```
body {
background-color:#f1f1f1;
font-family: georgia,sans-serif;
color:#333;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}


#wrapper {
width:70%;
background-color:#f8f8f8;
margin:0 auto;
border-left:1px solid #ccc;
border-right:1px solid #ccc;
}

#wrapper1{
width:98%;
background-color:#f8f8f8;
margin:0 auto;
border-left:1px solid #ccc;
border-right:1px solid #ccc;
}



#content {
width:76%;
float:left;
padding:10px;
}


#content input{

margin:5;

}





#content br{
clear: left;
}



.navbar {
    position:relative;

    width:90%;
    height:20px;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:15px;
    border-radius:3px;
    /*-moz-border-radius:3px;*/
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* main menu styles */
#nav,#nav ul {
    font-family:verdana;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;

}
#nav {
    height:50px;
    left:0%;
    overflow:hidden;
    top:0;

}
#nav li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}
#nav li a {
    background:url(bg-menu.png) no-repeat center top;
    color:#fff;/*text color on menu*/
    display:block;
    float:left;
    font-size:14px;
    height:51px;
    line-height:40px;
    padding:0 10px;
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
    z-index:20;
}
#nav li:first-child a {
    background:url(bg-menu.png) no-repeat left top;
    padding-left:45px;
}
#nav li ul li:first-child a {
    background-image:none;
    padding-left:10px;
}
#nav li.pad {
    background:url(bg-menu.png) no-repeat right top;
    display:block;
    height:51px;
    width:45px;
}
#nav li.xpad {
    background:url(bg-menu.png) no-repeat center top;
    display:block;
    height:51px;
    width:165px;
}


#nav ul {

    background:#2A3241;
    height:auto;
    padding:10px 0;
    position:absolute;
    top:-115px;
    width:120px;
    z-index:10;

    border-radius:8px; /*some css3*/
    /*-moz-border-radius:8px;*/
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    transition:0.8s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
/*  -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);*/
    -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-transition:0.8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:0.8s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
#nav ul li {
    width:280px;
}
#nav ul li a {
    background:transparent;
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    width:160px;
}

 #nav:hover {
    height:200px;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
    -moz-transform:translate(0,161px); /*some css3 - moves entire sub menu box down*/
    -o-transform:translate(0,161px);
    -webkit-transform:translate(0,161px);
}
#nav a:hover,#nav li:hover > a {/*changes color of text when mouse over*/
    color:#d632f2;

}
```

Menu

```
<div class="navbar">

       <ul id="nav">
    <li><a ></a></li>   
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>                     
                    </ul>


            </li>
 <li class="xpad"></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Testing</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Single Asset</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Asset Groups</a></li>
                    </ul>

            </li>
 <li class="xpad"></li>     
            <li><a href="#">Reports</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>                 
                    </ul>

            </li>
 <li class="xpad"></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Administration</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
                    </ul>

            </li>
 <li><a ></a></li>          
            <li class="pad"></li>
        </ul>
</div> <!-- end #nav -->
```

Test Page

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<meta name="description" content="" />

<meta name="keywords" content="" />

<meta name="author" content="" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"  media="screen" />





<title>Menu Test</title>

</head>

    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">
<?php include('nav.php'); ?>


<div id="content">
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value = "1"><br />
<label for="phone">Phone Number</label>';
<input <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" value = "2"><br />
<h1>Heading1</h1>
<h2>Heading2</h2>
<h3>Heading3</h3>
<h4>Heading4</h4>
<h5>Heading5</h5>



<h3>Paragraph Element</h3>

<p>

Quisque pellentesque sodales aliquam. Morbi mollis neque eget arcu egestas non ultrices neque volutpat. Nam at nunc lectus, id vulputate purus. In et turpis ac mauris viverra iaculis. Cras sed elit a purus ultrices iaculis eget sit amet dolor. Praesent ac libero dolor, id viverra libero. Mauris aliquam nibh vitae eros sodales fermentum. Fusce cursus est varius ante vehicula eget ultrices felis eleifend. Nunc pharetra rutrum nibh et lobortis. Morbi vitae venenatis velit.

</p>

<p>

Quisque pellentesque sodales aliquam. Morbi mollis neque eget arcu egestas non ultrices neque volutpat. Nam at nunc lectus, id vulputate purus. In et turpis ac mauris viverra iaculis. Cras sed elit a purus ultrices iaculis eget sit amet dolor. Praesent ac libero dolor, id viverra libero. Mauris aliquam nibh vitae eros sodales fermentum. Fusce cursus est varius ante vehicula eget ultrices felis eleifend. Nunc pharetra rutrum nibh et lobortis. Morbi vitae venenatis velit.

</p>

<h3>Another Heading Starting Point</h3>

<p>

Quisque pellentesque sodales aliquam. Morbi mollis neque eget arcu egestas non ultrices neque volutpat. Nam at nunc lectus, id vulputate purus. In et turpis ac mauris viverra iaculis. Cras sed elit a purus ultrices iaculis eget sit amet dolor. Praesent ac libero dolor, id viverra libero. Mauris aliquam nibh vitae eros sodales fermentum. Fusce cursus est varius ante vehicula eget ultrices felis eleifend. Nunc pharetra rutrum nibh et lobortis. Morbi vitae venenatis velit.

</p>

<p>

Quisque pellentesque sodales aliquam. Morbi mollis neque eget arcu egestas non ultrices neque volutpat. Nam at nunc lectus, id vulputate purus. In et turpis ac mauris viverra iaculis. Cras sed elit a purus ultrices iaculis eget sit amet dolor. Praesent ac libero dolor, id viverra libero. Mauris aliquam nibh vitae eros sodales fermentum. Fusce cursus est varius ante vehicula eget ultrices felis eleifend. Nunc pharetra rutrum nibh et lobortis. Morbi vitae venenatis velit.

</p>

</div> <!-- end #content -->



        </div> <!-- End #wrapper -->

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the

```
<input
```

before your input fields. That may help.

Comment: that extra input was just something that crept in with cutting and pasting this example - made no difference.